Symmetric difference as a group law
Let $D$ be any set and define $\mathcal{P}(D)=\{A:A\subseteq D\}$ to be the power set of $D$.
For any $A,B\in\mathcal{P}(D)$, define the symmetric difference operation $$A*B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A).$$
It is pretty easily shown that $G(D)=(\mathcal{P}(D),*)$ is an abelian group, and its identity element is the empty set $\varnothing$. I will include a proof at the end of the question.
Anyway, consider any subset $A\in\mathcal P(D)$ and observe that
$$A*A=(A\setminus A)\cup (A\setminus A)=\varnothing\cup\varnothing=\varnothing.$$
Thus every element of $G(D)$ has order $2$. Because of this, when $D=\{d_1,d_2,...,d_N\}$ is finite, we can say two things.
Firstly, $G(D)$ is generated by the singleton subsets of $D$:
$$G(D)=\left\{(a_1\{d_1\})*(a_2\{d_2\})*\cdots *(a_N\{d_N\}):a_i\in\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\right\},$$
where we define $0\{d_i\}=\varnothing$ and $1\{d_i\}=\{d_i\}$, and $(a\{d\})*(b\{d\})=(a+_2b)\{d\}$, with $+_2$ being addition modulo $2$.
Secondly, we can define an isomorphism $\phi:\mathcal P(D)\to (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^N$ by the map
$$\phi:(a_1\{d_1\})*(a_2\{d_2\})*\cdots *(a_N\{d_N\})\mapsto (a_1,a_2,...,a_N).$$
This is an isomorphism because
$$\begin{align}
\phi\left(A*B\right)&=\phi\Big((a_1+_2b_1)\{d_1\}*\cdots*(a_N+_2b_N)\{d_N\}\Big)\\
&=\Big(a_1+_2b_1,...,a_N+_2b_N\Big)\\
&=\Big(a_1,...,a_N\Big)+\Big(b_1,...,b_N\Big)\\
&=\phi(A)+\phi(B).
\end{align}$$
Here, $A=(a_1\{d_1\})*\cdots*(a_N\{d_N\})$ and $B=(b_1\{d_1\})*\cdots *(b_N\{d_N\})$.
The upshot is that $G(D)\cong (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^{|D|}$ when $D$ is finite.

My question is, what happens when $D=\Bbb Z$ or $D=\Bbb R$? Or more generally, when $D$ is not finite? Can we still decompose $G(D)$ into copies of $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$?
So far, I have made little progress. If $D$ is countably infinite (in bijection with $\Bbb Z$), we can enumerate the generators $\{\{d_1\},\{d_2\},...\}$, and its clear that every finite subset of $D$ can be written as a finite combination of the generators it contains. However, I am not sure how to deal with infinite subsets of $D$, because I don't know how we can appropriately take the $*$ operation infinitely many times.
When $D$ is uncountably infinite (such as $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$), I have no idea how to proceed. Any ideas?

Here is a proof that $G(D)=(\mathcal P(D), *)$ is an abelian group.
If $A,B\in\mathcal P(D)$, we have $A\setminus B, B\setminus A\in\mathcal P(D)$, so that $A*B\in\mathcal P(D)$. That is, $G(D)$ is closed under $*$.
We have that $*$ is commutative, because
$$B*A=(B\setminus A)\cup (A\setminus B)=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)= A*B.$$
The identity element is $\varnothing$ because
$$A*\varnothing=(A\setminus\varnothing)\cup(\varnothing\setminus A)=A\cup\varnothing=A,$$
and every element is its own inverse as shown above.

Symmetric difference is usually denoted $A\Delta B$ or $A\triangle B$, not $A*B$.

Where is the "group action" referred to in the title?

@Kan't I've changed it

Associate to every subset $A$ of $D$ its indicator function $\chi_A\colon D\to 2=\{0,1\}$, given by
$$\chi_A(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 &\text{if }x\in A\\
0 &\text{otherwise.}
\end{array}\right.$$
We know that $P(D)$ is naturally isomorphic to the set $2^D=\{\chi_A\mid A\in P(D)\}$, by associating each subset with its indicator function.
We can also identify $2$ with the field with $2$-elements, and thus  consider $2^D$ as being the set $\mathbb{F}_2^D$ of functions from the set $D$ to the field $\mathbb{F}_2$. This set has a natural structure as an $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space by pointwise addition. This addition corresponds precisely to the symmetric difference. That is, $\chi_A + \chi_B = \chi_{(A\Delta B)}$. This is essentially your observation, as an $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space structure is equivalent to a $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ action.
Since this is a vector space, assuming the Axiom of Choice it has a basis $\mathcal{B}$. That basis consists of functions $\chi_B$ with the property that every subset of $D$ can be written uniquely as a symmetric difference of finitely many subsets from among those that occur in elements of $\mathcal{B}$. In fact, you can assume that your set $\mathcal{B}$ includes the singletons (which yield linearly independent indicator functions), since every linearly independent set can be extended to a basis. So assuming the Axiom of Choice, there is definitely an isomorphism of $(P(D),\Delta)$ with a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{F}_2$, infinitely many when $D$ is infinite. So for example, $(P(\mathbb{Z}),\Delta)$ will be isomorphic to a direct sum of $2^{\aleph_0}$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.
However, you cannot exhibit an explicit basis/isomorphism in general. This because it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there are groups of exponent $2$ that are not trivial but have trivial automorphism group, which means that they do not have an $\mathbb{F}_2$-basis.
You can't really define "infinite sums" in this vector space (there is no norm through which you can take limits). If you had a sequence of subsets $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ and attempted to define something like "partial sums",
$$S_1 = A_1, S_2=A_1\Delta A_2,\ldots, S_n=A_1\Delta\cdots\Delta A_n,$$
you could consider $\limsup S_n$ and $\liminf S_n$, and define the "infinite symmetric difference" to be their common value if defined. But in "most" cases you will have that these two sets are not equal.

This works, thank you
